# differentiate admin and users with session php

Tags: php

I successfully made a PHP login system with session but I need to differentiate the users to their respective role such as admin and users and direct them to their respective page. I already made a column in my database entitled 'user_role'..

here's my code..

**login_inc.php**

```
    <?php
   session_start();
   require('dbconnect.php');


   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['username']);
      $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['password']); 

      $sql = "SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username = '$myusername' && password = '$mypassword'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    //  $active = $row['active'];

      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

      if($count == 1) 
      {
         $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
     //    header("Location: ../index.php");
      }

      else
      {
         alert('Invalid Username or Password');
         header("Refresh: 1,../index.php");
         die();
      }
   }

?>
```

Comment: You should have to maintain user type in database field & same type when user logged in maintain in session.

Comment: Just fetch data from user_role column and set that type in session same as login_user.

Comment: @GajananKolpuke.. I already done that but I've got an error that the $user_role variable for my user type is unidentified?

Comment: undefined rather

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create another variable in database that assume 0 or 1. In case 0 Is normal user, One is admin.
Add in SQL query the new field and Add another if for check the value privilege .

```
$privilege = mysql_result($result,"privilege")
```

Comment: I already got my user_role column in database. and tried this code